# Swift - Pass data back to last opened view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, pass-data

I'm working on a app where the user can create a tournament.
What I'm trying to do right now is when the user taps on the button "Select players" inside the `CreateTournamentViewController`, a `PlayersTableViewController` should pop up.

Then the user selects all the players. After he is finished and tapped on "Done", the `PlayersTableViewController` should close and pass the data back to the `CreateTournamentViewController`.

Now my question is: What is the best way to achieve this?

I would do it like this: `CreateTournamentViewController` has an array `var players = [Player]`. After selecting the players in the `PlayersTableViewController`, I would set this player array: `players = createTournamentViewController.players`.

But is this really the best way to do it?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Delegate` pattern to do this, your tournamentViewController can be delegate of your `PlayersTableViewController` and when user select his players you can pass through one method like `func playersWasSelected(players:[player])`,

I hope this helps you